Recursive Sequence convergence
Let $(b_n)_n$ be a nonnegative sequence and such that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_{n+1}^2-b_n=a>0$$
Show that $(b_n)_n$ is convergent
My approach is write $a_n=b^2_{n+1}-b_{n}$ and there exists an integer $N$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$, $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$. Write $b=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}>1$ which is a solution to the equation $y^2-y-a=0$. Then $$|b_{n+1}-b|\leq |b^2_{n+1}-b^2|=|a_n+b_n-a-b|\leq |a_n-a|+|b_n-b|=\epsilon+|b_n-b|$$
This means that $b_{n+1}$ is closer to b than $b_{n+1}$. What is the next step to bound the inequality? Show I use try to show the boundedness and monotonicty of $b_n$ to proceed? Thanks

Instead of $|b_{n+1}-b|\leq |b^2_{n+1}-b^2|$ write $|b_{n+1}-b|=\frac {|b^2_{n+1}-b^2|}{|b_{n+1}+b|}\le \frac {|b^2_{n+1}-b^2|} b$.

Thanks so it reduces to $|b_{n+1}-b|\leq \frac{1}{b}(\epsilon+|b_n-b|)$. I am sorry still bit confused on how can you argue that the right hand side can be arbitrarily small

@nagnag Then you have $|b_{n+2} - b| \le \frac{1}{b} \epsilon + \frac{1}{b}[\frac{1}{b}(\epsilon+|b_n-b|)] = (1/b + 1/b^2)\epsilon + \frac{1}{b^2}|b_n - b|$, $\cdots$?

Consider $0 < \varepsilon < a$ (the second constraint will allow us to avoid working with negative numbers later on). We know, that there is some $N$, such that:
$$n > N \implies |b_{n+1}^2 - b_n - a| < \varepsilon$$
We can rewrite that inequality:
$$b_n + a - \varepsilon < b_{n+1}^2 < b_n +a + \varepsilon$$
$$\sqrt{b_n + a - \varepsilon} < b_{n+1} < \sqrt{b_n +a + \varepsilon}$$
Simmilarily:
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{b_n +a - \varepsilon} + a - \varepsilon} < \sqrt{b_{n+1} + a - \varepsilon} < b_{n+2}$$
and
$$b_{n+2}< \sqrt{b_{n+1} +a + \varepsilon} < \sqrt{\sqrt{b_n +a + \varepsilon} + a + \varepsilon}$$
By repeating that inequalities we can obtain:
$$\sqrt{a-\varepsilon + \sqrt{\dots + \sqrt{a - \varepsilon + b_n}}} < b_{n+k} < \sqrt{a+\varepsilon + \sqrt{\dots + \sqrt{a + \varepsilon + b_n}}}$$
and denote:
$$l_k = \sqrt{a-\varepsilon + \sqrt{\dots + \sqrt{a - \varepsilon + b_n}}}$$
$$r_k = \sqrt{a+\varepsilon + \sqrt{\dots + \sqrt{a + \varepsilon + b_n}}}$$

Let's evaluate the limit of $r_k$ (limit of $l_k$ can be done symmetrically).
First of all I will show that the limit exists by showing that the sequence is monotonic and bounded. For convenience denote $a + \varepsilon = \alpha$. By definition we have:
$$r_1 = \sqrt{\alpha + b_n} \qquad r_{k+1} = \sqrt{r_k + \alpha}$$
Since $a > 0$ and $b_n \geqslant 0$ we have $r_k > 0$.
Case $1$: $b_n \leqslant \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4\alpha}}{2}$
Let's show that:
$$r_k \leqslant \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4\alpha}}{2} \implies r_{k+1} \leqslant\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4\alpha}}{2}$$
We have:
$$r_{k+1} \leqslant\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4\alpha}}{2}$$
$$\sqrt{r_k + \alpha}\leqslant\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4\alpha}}{2}$$
$$4r_k + 4\alpha \leqslant 1  + 1 + 4\alpha + 2\sqrt{1 + 4\alpha}$$
$$r_k \leqslant \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4\alpha}}{2}$$
In addition the same manipulation can be done to show that: $r_1 \leqslant \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4\alpha}}{2}$, thus from induction it falls that this inequality holds for all $k$.
Now I will prove that sequence is increasing:
$$r_{k+1} \geqslant r_k \iff \sqrt{r_k + \alpha} \geqslant r_k \iff r_k + \alpha \geqslant r_k^2$$
With the fact $r_k > 0$ this is equivalent to:
$$r_k \leqslant \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4\alpha}}{2}$$
but it was shown te be true for all $k$, thus sequence is increasing and bounded by $\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4\alpha}}{2}$, hence it has a limit.
Case $2$: $b_n > \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4\alpha}}{2}$
Very similar manipulation as in the Case $1$ will lead us to fact, that sequence is decreasing. Obviously it is bounded by $0$, hence in this case it has a limit too.
We can now denote:
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}r_k = R$$
But $R$ must satisfy $R \geqslant 0$ and $R = \sqrt{R + \alpha}$, thus:
$$R = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4\alpha}}{2} = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4\alpha + 4\varepsilon}}{2}$$
Similarily we can denote $\lim_{k\to\infty}l_k = L$, where:
$$L = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4\alpha - 4\varepsilon}}{2}$$

Let's choose $K$ such that for $k > K$ we have both:
$$|l_k - L| < \varepsilon \qquad |r_k - R| < \varepsilon$$
Now we are allowed to write for $n > N$ and $k > K$:
$$\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4a - 4\varepsilon}}{2} - \varepsilon < b_{n+k} < \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4a + 4\varepsilon}}{2} + \varepsilon$$
By simple manipulations we can show:
$$\sqrt{1 + 4a - 4\varepsilon} \geqslant \sqrt{1 + 4a} - 4\varepsilon$$
$$\sqrt{1 + 4a} + 4\varepsilon\geqslant \sqrt{1 + 4a + 4\varepsilon}$$
Thus:
$$\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4a}}{2} - 3\varepsilon < b_{n+k} < \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4a}}{2} + 3\varepsilon$$
$$\left|b_{n+k} - \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4a}}{2}\right| < 3\varepsilon$$
We can always pick $\varepsilon = \min\{a, \frac{\varepsilon'}{3}\}$ to get:
$$\left|b_n - \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4a}}{2}\right| < \varepsilon'$$
for any $\varepsilon'$ and accordingly large $n$. So ${b_n}$ is convergent.
